# Unable to add any wordpress extension on my website

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

my website is working properly, but i can't add any extension anymore, today i can't even update my WordPress core. it show 504 error gateway. i disabled most of plugins, but the dashboard is always slow, especially when dealing with WordPress updates and plugins update or adding new one.
anyone can help please.

Comment: Are you able to show your logs? But it seems like you have insufficient hardware.

Comment: my wordpress site is hosted in OVH , CPU : 1 vCore 2.4GHz
RAM : 4 Go
Stockage : 25 Go SSD